# Importing multiple csv files into a concatenated dataframe with each column appended in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, data-analysis

I have many csv files which look like this:

**file_1.csv**

```
name  num
Ab     8
Dd     9
Cc     20
Kk     69
```

**file_2.csv**

```
name  num
Ab    23
Dd    3
Kk    20
Jj    30
```

and so on...
Now, you see there's a name that may not appear on the first csv but does in some other csv.

Now, my primary concern is getting them all together in a single dataframe (concatenate), like this:
**big_df**

```
name num num2 num3....numN
 Ab   8    23   ...
 Dd   9     3   ...
```

where N is the number of csv files with the column num

---

I dug around a fair bit looking for a solution, and this is what I got:

```
path = 'E:\\my_path\\**\\*.csv'
all_rec = iglob(path, recursive = True)
dataframes = (pd.read_csv(f, sep = ';', skiprows = 1, header = None) for f in all_rec)
big_df = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index = True)
```

Didn't really work out for me.

Comment: Are the file naming conventions truly different (some can have underscores, others may not) or is that a typo in your question? Do they all have the number somewhere in the name? Is that the only number?

Comment: No, they are the same (all have underscores with subsequent numbering).

Comment: pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index = True, axis = 1)

Comment: @AjayShah 'No objects to concatenate'

Comment: Use [] instead of () in previous lines where you define dataframes. pd.concat takes a list of dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of files however you want. I don't know if you have other `.csv` files in that directory, so modify if necessary.

The key here is that you want to set `name` to be the index, that way `pd.concat` uses that to align the `DataFrames` when you join them. You can use `regex` to get the file numbers, and then append that to the column name.

```
import os
import re
import pandas as pd

path = 'define_your_path'
files = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if '.csv' in x]
#['file_1.csv', 'file_2.csv']

lst = []
for f in files:
    lst.append(pd.read_csv(path+f)
                 .set_index('name')
                 .add_suffix(re.search('.*_(.*)\.', f).group(1)))

big_df = pd.concat(lst, axis=1, sort=False)
```

#### Output: `big_df`

```
    num1  num2
Ab   8.0  23.0
Dd   9.0   3.0
Cc  20.0   NaN
Kk  69.0  20.0
Jj   NaN  30.0
```

---

#### Input Data:

file_1.csv:

```
name,num
Ab,8
Dd,9
Cc,20
Kk,69
```

file_2.csv:

```
name,num
Ab,23
Dd,3
Kk,20
Jj,30
```